# Log a squared variable or square a logged variable

Tags: estimation, logarithm

I'm estimating an OLS log-log model like so:

\begin{equation}
ln(y) = \alpha + log(x_1) + \varepsilon
\end{equation}

and now want to account for non-linearities in the response of $ln(y)$ to $log(x1)$.

Do I now estimate:

\begin{equation}
ln(y) = \alpha + log(x_1) + log(x_1)^2 + \varepsilon
\end{equation}

or:

\begin{equation}
ln(y) = \alpha + log(x_1) + log(x_1^2) + \varepsilon
\end{equation}

These obviously give me different results - my question is, which criteria do I use to make this decision?

In my case, $x_1$ is GDP and $y$ is carbon emissions.

Comment: Fantastic Glen_b! Many thanks for this - I should have of course realised that $log(x^2_1)$ is equal to $2*log(x_1)$ and therefore perfectly collinear with $log(x_1)$ and hence is dropped in a regression. I shall use $log(x_1)^2$. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: Done. $\qquad\!$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\log(x_1^2)=2\cdot\log(x_1)$.

Consequently, $\text{cor}(\log(x_1),\log(x_1^2))=1$.

The log of the square adds no value when the log is already there.